# MFMailComposeViewController not called

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement MFMailComposeViewController() in two cells (Subject "feedback"and "feedback2").

When I select each cell, "feedback" works well, but "feedback2" is not called.

It seems not difficult issue but I find it difficult to fix the problem.

```
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let message = "hey download this app"
            let shareView = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [message], applicationActivities: nil)
            self.present(shareView, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let mailCompose = MFMailComposeViewController()

            mailCompose.mailComposeDelegate = self

            mailCompose.setToRecipients(["gmail.com"])

            mailCompose.setSubject("feedback")

            mailCompose.setMessageBody("text", isHTML: false)

            if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()

            {

                self.present(mailCompose, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
                let mailCompose = MFMailComposeViewController()

                mailCompose.mailComposeDelegate = self

                mailCompose.setToRecipients(["ba@mail.com"])

                mailCompose.setSubject("feedback2")

                mailCompose.setMessageBody("text", isHTML: false)

                if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()

                {

                    self.present(mailCompose, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }

            else{

                print("error...!")

            }
        }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: @risa18 any errors?I guess you are calling indexPath.row==2 inside indexPath.row==1 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `else if indexPath.row == 2` is indented one level too deeply – its `else` refers to `!MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()`, not the previous `indexPath` check. You'll need to shift that branch outwards one level to get the effect you want.

For the future, it might be easier to debug if you refactor out a single method for all your mail-composing:

```
private func sendMail(to recipient: String, subject: String) {
    if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        return
    }

    let mailCompose = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailCompose.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailCompose.setToRecipients([recipient])
    mailCompose.setSubject(subject)
    mailCompose.setMessageBody("text", isHTML: false)
    self.present(mailCompose, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row {
        case 0: /* activity view controller stuff */ break;
        case 1:
            sendMail(to: "gmail.com", subject: "feedback")
            break;
        case 2:
            sendMail(to: "ba@mail.com", subject: "feedback2")
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is also really useful to always have a bracket at the same depth as its `else/if` statement to make sure this won't happen any more.

Comment: And please check if you can send email before creating and setting up the composer.